# How to hide/show the menu using classList toogle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating an interactive hamburger button that shows and hides the menu. what I am trying to achieve here is when I click the hamburger button, the menu shows up and when I click transformed "X" button, the menu hides itself vice versa. I would appreciate tips. Thank you so much.

```js
function myFunction(y) {
  y.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[class*="bar"] {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #000a;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}


/* Menu */

.menu {
  padding: 50px 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.menu>a {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 10px;
  display: block;
  color: #fffa;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id="menu" class="menu">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Work</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: add toggle class with display none

Comment: You have done everything except connect those two. See my answer. I have also **added some special effects**, if you like. `:D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done everything except connect those two. You just need to add the following CSS:

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}

.change + .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```js
function myFunction(y) {
  y.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[class*="bar"] {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #000a;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}


/* Menu */

.menu {
  padding: 50px 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.menu>a {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 10px;
  display: block;
  color: #fffa;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

.change + .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id="menu" class="menu">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Work</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</div>
```

**Bonus**

If you want a nice fading animation, you can also use opacity.

```js
function myFunction(y) {
  y.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[class*="bar"] {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #000a;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}


/* Menu */

.menu {
  padding: 50px 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.menu>a {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 10px;
  display: block;
  color: #fffa;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.change + .menu {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id="menu" class="menu">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Work</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate it. Love your website!

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this code**

```js
function myFunction(y) {
 y.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
[class*="bar"] {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #000a;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 7px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 7px);
}
.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -7px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -7px);
}
.menu {
  padding: 50px 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.menu>a {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 10px;
  display: block;
  color: #fffa;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.menu {
  max-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.change + .menu {
  max-height: 500px;
} 
.change + .menu,
.change ,
.menu {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id="menu" class="menu">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Work</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</div>
```